# In a switch statement is it possible to use a modulo operator in each case?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, modulo

Is it possible to do something like this using switch statements?

```
switch(foo) {
    case %bar==0:
    //Do stuff
    break;
}
```

To be more clear, the switch statement should check if foo is divided by something is 0/if foo is divisible by something in each case.

Comment: Not without resorting to some ugly hacks. Use `if-else` statements intead.

Comment: @helpermethod That's a bit icky, I plan to have a lot of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A switch compares the result of ONE evaluation such as `fn(foo)`, `foo+bar`, `foo%bar` against various possible results. You want to compute multiple values [`foo%bar1, foo%bar2,...]` and find the first that's equal to 0.

I don't see a way of making that happen with switch (well, you could use the fall-through, but that would be a roundabout way of going at it)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be any of the Array iterators, with bar defined as  an array of values.

```
function fooMod(foo){
    var A= [];
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].forEach(function(itm){
        if(foo%itm=== 0){
            A.push(itm+' is a factor of '+foo);
        }
        else{
            A.push(itm+' is not a factor of '+foo);
        }

    });
    return A;
}
```

**fooMod(24).join('\n');**

```
/*  returned value: (String)
2 is a factor of 24
3 is a factor of 24
4 is a factor of 24
5 is not a factor of 24
6 is a factor of 24
7 is not a factor of 24
8 is a factor of 24
9 is not a factor of 24
*/
```

Comment: **+1** I couldn't accept you, but I think posterity will find you more useful.